# How to write a function that takes in a string and removes any consonants before the first vowel

Tags: swift, function, if-statement

So I am fairly new to Swift(trying to self-learn) , and I am already stuck. Im trying to create a function that takes in a string as a parameter, checks if there is any consonants before the first vowel, and removes it if so. So if the user inputs his name as Michael, ichael would print out. I have written

```
func shortNameForName(name: String) -> String {

    let shortName = name.lowercaseString
    let vowelSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "aeiou")

    /* I know here i can create an if statement that basically states that if the first
       character of the string does not contain the vowelset, remove it, but I don't know
       the syntax/how to write it */

    return shortName
}

print(shortNameForName("Michael"))
```

Comment: You may want to do some googling on String.index. You can associate an index with the position of the first vowel, and then take the substring from that index to the end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this.

```
func shortNameForName(name: String) -> String {

    let charSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "aeiou")

    if let index = name.lowercased().rangeOfCharacter(from: charSet)?.lowerBound {
        return name.substring(from: index)
    }

    return ""
}

shortNameForName(name: "Michael")
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using Swift 3 and a regular expression:

```
func shortName(for name: String) -> String {
    // regular expression for consonants (= not vowels) in the beginning
    let regularExpression = "^[^aeiou]+"

    guard let firstVowelRange = name.range(
        of: regularExpression,
        options: [.caseInsensitive, .regularExpression],
        range: nil
    ) else {
        return name
    }

    // if the reg exp matched something, remove it
    return name.substring(from: firstVowelRange.upperBound)
}

print(shortName(for: "Michael"))
print(shortName(for: "MMMichael"))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

Try this

```
func shortNameForName(name: String) -> String {
    let vowel = "aeiou" // Maybe add the 'y'
    let shortName = name.lowercaseString
    let firstLetter = shortName.[shortName.startIndex]

    if vowel.rangeOfString(firstLetter) != nil {
        shortName.remove(at: shortName.startIndex)
    }
    return shortName
}
```

PS: Not tested

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this using `NSRegularExpression`:

```
func shortNameForName(name: String) -> String {

    let pattern = "^[^aeiou]+([aeiou])"
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
    let shortName = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: name, range: NSRange(0..<name.utf16.count), withTemplate: "$1")
    return shortName //or `shortName.lowercased()` if you prefer
}

print(shortNameForName(name: "Michael")) //->ichael
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
func shortNameFromName(_ name: String) -> String {
    let lowercaseName = name.lowercased()
    let vowelSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "aeiou")

    if let index = lowercaseName.rangeOfCharacter(from: vowelSet)?.lowerBound {
        return String(lowercaseName[index...])
    } else {
        return lowercaseName
    }
}
```